# How to hide public methods within inheritable class

Tags: android

I want to hide some methods within inheritable class from users. 
For Example:

```
public class Test extends TextView {

    public Test(Context context) {
          super.onCreate(context);
    }

    /* hide this method */
    @Override
    protected void setText(CharSequence text) {
          super.setText(text);
    }
}
```

And then I don't want to see this method within Test class.
How can I do it? Sorry for my English

Comment: How do you mean hide it?  Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "hide". You could just remove it as it only calls super anyway and it's public in `TextView`, so there's no need to have it in your `Test` class. If by "hide" you mean make it `private`, that's not possible -- it's defined by `TextView` to be public and you cannot reduce the visibility of an inherited method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a design problem since hiding it seems a bit dirty as a base class assigned to subclass should still be able to call base class methods.

You could, however, do one of 2 things.

1. Mark the method as deprecated.  Note: deprecated is usually used to tell people to not use the method b/c it will soon be removed but still presently works whereas here it would not work at all (presumably)...

   AND throw UnsupportedOperationException in the method so that you / others catch it early if it is called.

   ```
   /*
    * @deprecated Do not call this method.
    */
   @Deprecated
   @Override
   protected void setText(CharSequence text) {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not supported");
   }
   ```
2. Instead of subclassing consider composition.  By this I mean make a class that wraps the desired class and expose only what you want.  If you need a common interface between the original class and your wrapper class, create an interface that they both implement and use the interface but instantiate using your new class.

Comment: I should also mention that I like the second option more, but it's more work.